# Error when running linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm receiving this error

```
"{"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."}"
```

Here is the code that it errors on.

```
var summaryViewModel = new YogaSpaceSummaryViewModel
            {
                SpaceImage = (from u in space.Images orderby u.Ordering ascending select u.ImageThumbnail).First(),
                Title = space.Overview.Title,
                SpaceId = space.YogaSpaceId,
                DateCreated = space.DateCreated.ToShortDateString(),
                StepsToList = space.StepsToList,
                Status = space.Status
            };
```

which part of this code here

```
YogaSpaceOverviewViewModel overviewViewModel = new YogaSpaceOverviewViewModel();

        foreach (YogaSpace space in yogaSpaces)
        {
            var summaryViewModel = new YogaSpaceSummaryViewModel
            {
                SpaceImage = (from u in space.Images orderby u.Ordering ascending select u.ImageThumbnail).First(),
                Title = space.Overview.Title,
                SpaceId = space.YogaSpaceId,
                DateCreated = space.DateCreated.ToShortDateString(),
                StepsToList = space.StepsToList,
                Status = space.Status
            };

            overviewViewModel.YogaSpaceSummarys.Add(summaryViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: As the message suggests, check if any of your previously opened/used DataReaders is properly closed.

Comment: how would I check that?

Comment: Post the code for DB connections

Comment: If the datareader is null.  Make sure when the reader is closed you set it to null.  It is automatically null initially.

Comment: I placed a .ToList() after yogaSpaces in the foreach loop and that seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to wrap downward using a using so the scope will cause all objects to bedisposed. Also, to circumvent a lzy loading issue with disposed datacontext's you will probally be better served to `ToList()` ot `FirstOrDefault()` any result you are returning to ensure the collection has been enumerated and if the context is disposed then everything is dandy.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="DatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Database.csdl|res://*/Database.ssdl|res://*/Database.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=passowrd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

**Enable** MultipleActiveResultSets in Webconfig

Answer (score 0):

Add MultipleActiveResultSets=true to the provider part of your connection string (where Data Source, Initial Catalog, etc. are specified).